# Python: What happens to unnamed objects?

Tags: python, memory

Example:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val

a1 = A(1)
a2 = A(2)
a20 = A(20)

dct = {a1 : A(10), a2: a20}

del dct[a1] # what happens to the unnamed `A(10)`?
```

Since there's nothing pointing or referencing the "unnamed" `A(10)`, what happens to it?

A slightly more contrived case:

```
dct = {"key": ("first", [2])}

l = dct["key"][1] # points to the `[2]` list

del dct["key"]
```

In this case

1. The `("first", [2])` tuple is unnamed.
2. The `[2]` list is named `l`.

When we `del dct["key"]` what happens to the tuple? I know the list `l` sticks around since there's still a reference to it.

Comment: They are eventually garbage collected (though as an implementation detail, strings in module source code are interned so the `"first"` string in the tuple would actually be retained).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that for yourself by implementing the **del** method.  This will allow you to see when the garbage collector removes object instances from memory:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val

  def __del__(self):
      print("object",self.val,"deleted")


a1 = A(1)
a2 = A(2)
a20 = A(20)

dct = {a1 : A(10), a2: a20}

print("deleting key a1...")
del dct[a1] # what happens to the unnamed `A(10)`?

print("deleting dct (no instance is deleted because of variables references)")
dct = 0

print("clearing variables")
a1 = a2 = a20 = 0
```

output:

```
deleting key a1...
object 10 deleted
deleting dct (no instance is deleted because of variables references)
clearing variables
object 1 deleted
object 2 deleted
object 20 deleted
```

In short, the object instances are automatically deleted when there are no longer any references to them.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify what "(no instance is deleted because of variables references)" means?

What I understood was:
1. Before executing `dct = 0`, we have: `dct == {a2: a20}`.
2. After executing `dct = 0`, we don't have a way to reference to `{a2: a20`, but are you also saying that `{a2: a20}` itself is still floating around because the `a2` and `a20` variable reference are still around?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as long as there is at least one reference from any variable (directly as in `a20` or indirectly as in `dct`) the object instance stays "alive".  When all references are gone, the object is automatically deleted from memory.  In this case variable `a20` still references  instance `A(20)` after clearing `dct` so the `A(20)` object remains alive until variable `a20` itself is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

For the second example, we can visualize it as follows:

[image]

You may visualize your first example yourself [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit).